# Sublimetext auto indent not working when typing two function in a row

Tags: sublime-text-3

If I type a function in sublime, then enter, the second line is auto indented. if I type end to close it automatically unindents as desired. But if you type two functions in a row the second one's end does not unindent. Why is this happening and how do I fix it. I'm using the built-in lua syntax and my settings are on default.

```
function whatever()
end
function whatever()
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. Please see below from the [Sublime Form](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/everything-you-n-ever-wanted-to-know-about-indentation-in-st3/26207):

- there are times when unindenting doesn’t work properly when there is an increase indentation immediately followed by (or with only blank/whitespace lines in between) a decrease indentation
  https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1262

[image]

It does not look like something a user can fix as it is a programming error.